# Ocutar varias URL con CSS

Tags: html, css

Hola me encentro con el siguiente problema:

Ya he ocultado un href que había en una página con el siguiente codigo CSS

```
.enlace_desactivado [href="https://bioconstruccion.com.mx/proyecto-en-proceso-centro-de-mexico/"] {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Ahora el problema es que son muchas URL que tienen en común parte de la URL `https://bioconstruccion.com.mx/proyecto-en-proceso...`

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera en la que por medio del CSS pueda indicar que todas las URL que tengan `/proyecto-en-proceso.......` **independientemente** de como siga las oculte.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Si muestras el código entero igual es mas fácil ayudarte por que podremos elegir maneras de seleccionar esos elementos más apropiadas a tu código.

Comment: Bueno en realidad estoy usando WPBakery Builder con un Post Grid y ahi estoy aplicando el CSS, lo que quería saber es si por medio de CSS puedo indicar que todos los enlaces que tengan /proyecto-en-proceso los oculte dentro de ese Post Grid y asi no tener que llenar de todos los enlaces el CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un selector de atributo de esta forma:

```
[href="la/url/a/evaluar"] {
  propiedad: valor;
}
```

Pero justo luego del atributo agregamos el operador `*` para que la búsqueda no sea exacta sino que tome como referencia el inicio del valor asignado en la evaluación quedando de esta forma:

Ejemplo:

```
    [href*="http://www.lomio.com/uno"] {
      display: none;
    }
```

Para tu caso pudiera quedar así:

```
<style>
    [href*="https://bioconstruccion.com.mx/proyecto-en-proceso/uno"] {
      display: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://bioconstruccion.com.mx/proyecto-en-proceso/uno/1" class="elementos-ocultos">Uno</a>
<a href="https://bioconstruccion.com.mx/proyecto-en-proceso/uno/2" class="elementos-ocultos">Dos</a>
<a href="https://bioconstruccion.com.mx/proyecto-en-proceso/uno/3" class="elementos-ocultos">Tres</a>
<a href="https://bioconstruccion.com.mx/proyecto-en-proceso/dos/4" class="elementos-ocultos">Cuatro</a>
<a href="https://bioconstruccion.com.mx/proyecto-en-proceso/tres/5" class="elementos-ocultos">Cinco</a>
```

[Créditos de la explicación](https://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors/)